# Support WebRTC for android and ios both?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webrtc, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I am making an application which gives  support to  webRTC for android & ios both for this I make a lot of R&D then I found an Ionic framework to support both platforms.  you can see [here/ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). no doubt it is a powerful tool for us in nowadays. and for supporting webRTC I have used [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/). because internally ionic use phone`s browser means for android it uses **Chrome** and for ios ,**safari** but the issue was there: older version of **Chrome** did not support for webRTC and safari did not till now. so with crosswalk webView all thing is working fine means calls are getting connecting and user A and B can communicate utterly but I am facing an issue of apk size which is also mentioned @ [crosswalk issues tracker.](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html) I have done all possible ways to reduce the size of apk which is mentioned there - by generation two apks , but apk size is still more than **25 mb**.

I found another way was to disable all instead of WebRTC -but I am not sure ,will it works or not / how to do that?

so can you please let me know how to solve this issue with the crosswalk. or is it possible or not ? if it is then how can I do this else please give me some references of plugins(webVisew) which supports webRTC.

thanks in advace.your help can save me thanks.

Comment: any suggestions :)